# How to install a package in Julia 1.0 (UndefVarError: Pkg not defined)

Tags: julia, plotly

I installed Julia 1.0, and want to make a simple plot. The first step is to type this on Julia:

```
Pkg.add("PyPlot")
```

However, an error occurs:

```
ERROR: UndefVarError: Pkg not defined.
```

The same thing happens when I type:

```
Pkg.status()
```

What's the best way to install a package in Julia? I use MacOS.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

In Julia 1.0, there are two ways to install a package. First, you can do

```
using Pkg
Pkg.add("Packagename")
```

Second, you can use the Pkg REPL mode by pressing `]` (similar to `?`, help mode, and `;`, shell mode):

```
(v1.0) pkg> add Packagename
```

You can find more information here: https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/stdlib/Pkg/#
and here (live demo): https://youtu.be/GBi__3nF-rM?t=28m1s

Julia 1.0 is brand new. It has been released a few days ago, so some packages aren't yet compatible with 1.0. Sometimes it helps to install the master branch of a package instead of the last tagged release. On my machine I had to do

```
(v1.0) pkg> add LaTeXStrings#master
(v1.0) pkg> add PyPlot
```

to get PyPlot to work. Hope this helps.

**UPDATE:** LaTeXStrings has been updated (tagged). The first line above is therefore not necessary anymore.

**UPDATE2:** Another (shorter) live demo can be found here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=76KL8aSz0Sg

**UPDATE3:** There is a third way of interacting with the package manager, namely "pkg strings":

```
using Pkg
pkg"add Packagename"
```

Comment: Your answer solved the problem, the comment is for the newly julia developers... obvious steps to make the code more cumbersome...

Answer (score 3):

As someone new to Julia, my initial confusion on the Julia 1.0 package manager was directly related to the OP's problem.  I have not used pre-Julia 1.0 REPL's, but it would appear that it used to be that `Pkg.add("Example")` worked right out of the box--no `using Pkg` was required.  There are examples floating around the web of this being the way to get started.  The new Julia user, like me, might not initially be aware of this change.

However, the Julia 1.0 REPL *requires* the user to explicitly state `using Pkg` before employing the `Pkg.add.("Example")` command.