# Julialang tells ERROR: UndefVarError: Pkg not defined

Tags: julia

On a ubuntu 16.04,I downloaded julialang 1.0 binary package from

```
https://julialang.org/downloads/
```

,and extract it under:

```
/usr/local/julia
```

changed own and group to root,and added bin and lib to corresponded path:

```
#Julia
export JULIA_HOME=/usr/local/julia
export PATH=$JULIA_HOME/bin:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$JULIA_HOME/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

then go to julia console to run:

```
Pkg.status()
```

got

```
ERROR: UndefVarError: Pkg not defined
```

anything I missed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install a package in Julia 1.0 (UndefVarError: Pkg not defined)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51793629/how-to-install-a-package-in-julia-1-0-undefvarerror-pkg-not-defined)

Comment: See my slightly more complete answer in the duplicate thread above: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51793781/2365675

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`Pkg` is no longer loaded by default, so it needs to be loaded:

```
julia> using Pkg
```