# Unable to Install packages for Julia 0.7 in Fedora 28 due to ERROR: Unsatisfiable requirements detected

Tags: julia

I recently updated my Fedora version from 25 to 28 and with it updated Julia from 0.6 to 0.7.0-alpha.99.

I am now trying to add packages but keep getting the same error:

```
Pkg.add("PyPlot")

  Updating registry at `~/.julia/registries/Uncurated`
  Updating git-repo `https://github.com/JuliaRegistries/Uncurated.git`
 Resolving package versions...
ERROR: Unsatisfiable requirements detected for package (unknown) [10745b16]:
 (unknown) [10745b16] log:
 ├─(unknown) [10745b16] has no known versions!
 └─found to have no compatible versions left with Distributions [31c24e10] 
   └─Distributions [31c24e10] log:
     ├─possible versions are: [0.1.0-0.1.4, 0.2.0-0.2.13, 0.3.0, 0.6.4-0.6.7, 0.7.0-0.7.6, 0.8.0-0.8.10, 0.9.0, 0.10.0-0.10.2, 0.11.0-0.11.1, 0.12.0-0.12.5, 0.13.0, 0.14.0-0.14.2, 0.15.0, 0.16.0-0.16.2] or uninstalled
     └─restricted to versions 0.16.2 by an explicit requirement, leaving only versions 0.16.2
Stacktrace:
 [1] #propagate_constraints!#61(::Bool, ::Function, ::Pkg.GraphType.Graph, ::Set{Int64}) at /builddir/build/BUILD/julia/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v0.7/Pkg/src/GraphType.jl:1005
 [2] propagate_constraints! at /builddir/build/BUILD/julia/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v0.7/Pkg/src/GraphType.jl:946 [inlined]
 [3] #simplify_graph!#121(::Bool, ::Function, ::Pkg.GraphType.Graph, ::Set{Int64}) at /builddir/build/BUILD/julia/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v0.7/Pkg/src/GraphType.jl:1460
 [4] simplify_graph! at /builddir/build/BUILD/julia/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v0.7/Pkg/src/GraphType.jl:1460 [inlined]
 [5] resolve_versions!(::Pkg.Types.Context, ::Array{Pkg.Types.PackageSpec,1}) at /builddir/build/BUILD/julia/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v0.7/Pkg/src/Operations.jl:291
 [6] #add_or_develop#52(::Array{Base.UUID,1}, ::Function, ::Pkg.Types.Context, ::Array{Pkg.Types.PackageSpec,1}) at /builddir/build/BUILD/julia/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v0.7/Pkg/src/Operations.jl:973
 [7] #add_or_develop at ./none:0 [inlined]
 [8] #add_or_develop#8(::Symbol, ::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{},Union{},Tuple{},NamedTuple{(),Tuple{}}}, ::Function, ::Pkg.Types.Context, ::Array{Pkg.Types.PackageSpec,1}) at /builddir/build/BUILD/julia/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v0.7/Pkg/src/API.jl:39
 [9] #add_or_develop at ./none:0 [inlined]
 [10] #add_or_develop#7 at /builddir/build/BUILD/julia/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v0.7/Pkg/src/API.jl:24 [inlined]
 [11] #add_or_develop at ./none:0 [inlined]
 [12] #add_or_develop#6 at /builddir/build/BUILD/julia/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v0.7/Pkg/src/API.jl:23 [inlined]
 [13] #add_or_develop at ./none:0 [inlined]
 [14] #add_or_develop#5 at /builddir/build/BUILD/julia/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v0.7/Pkg/src/API.jl:22 [inlined]
 [15] #add_or_develop at ./none:0 [inlined]
 [16] #add#9 at /builddir/build/BUILD/julia/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v0.7/Pkg/src/API.jl:44 [inlined]
 [17] add(::String) at /builddir/build/BUILD/julia/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v0.7/Pkg/src/API.jl:44
 [18] top-level scope at none:0
 [19] macro expansion at /builddir/build/BUILD/julia/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v0.7/REPL/src/REPL.jl:116 [inlined]
 [20] (::getfield(REPL, Symbol("##28#29")){REPL.REPLBackend})() at ./task.jl:257
```

The same thing happens with other packages (I have tried IJulia, Conda, Distributions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mention that you upgraded to `0.7.0-alpha.99`. There is a stable release for `0.7.0` which you should use instead of an alpha version. You can find it on https://julialang.org/downloads/ under "Previous stable release (v0.7.0)".

In general, as Julia is changing at a fast pace you should always use the binaries from [julialang.org](https://julialang.org/) instead of the binaries in your OS's package manager as they almost certainly won't be up to date (as in your case).

On a side note, from Julia 0.7 on the way to add packages has slightly changed. See my post here: [How to install a package in Julia 1.0 (UndefVarError: Pkg not defined)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51793629/how-to-install-a-package-in-julia-1-0-undefvarerror-pkg-not-defined/51793781#51793781)